# Um problema para resolver com expressões lambdas

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Fiz isso, para retornar uma lista. Acontece que dá erro, dizendo que não tem como transformar uma expressão anônima no tipo passado(objeto).

```
public List<Liberacao> PegaLiberacao()
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes.Join(
                contexto.ItensLibs,
                t1 => t1.IdOrcamento,
                t2 => t2.IdOrcamento,
                (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
                .Where(a => a.t1.IdOrcamento == a.t2.IdOrcamento)
                .Select(lib => new
                {
                    lib.t1.TipoVenda,
                    lib.t1.Vencimento,
                    lib.t1.Juros,
                    lib.t1.Entrada,
                    lib.t1.Acrescimo,
                    lib.t1.Desconto,
                    lib.t1.Mensagem,
                    lib.t1.DataLib,
                    lib.t1.Vendedor,
                    lib.t1.Cliente,
                    lib.t1.Filial,
                    lib.t2.Produto,
                    lib.t2.Qtde,
                    lib.t2.Unitario,
                    lib.t2.Custo,
                    lib.t2.CustoDiario,
                    lib.t2.UltCondicao,
                    lib.t2.Total
                }).ToList();

            return lista;
        }
```

E o erro é esse, ao retornar a minha lista:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT1**:
Essa é a minha model:

```
public class Autoriza
    {
        InetContext contexto = new InetContext();
        Liberacao liberacao = new Liberacao();

        public List<Liberacao> PegaLiberacao()
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes.Join(
                contexto.ItensLibs,
                t1 => t1.IdOrcamento,
                t2 => t2.IdOrcamento,
                (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
                .Where(a => a.t1.IdOrcamento == a.t2.IdOrcamento)
                .Select(lib => new Liberacao
                {
                    TipoVenda = lib.t1.TipoVenda,
                    Vencimento = lib.t1.Vencimento,
                    Juros = lib.t1.Juros,
                    Entrada = lib.t1.Entrada,
                    Acrescimo = lib.t1.Acrescimo,
                    Desconto = lib.t1.Desconto,
                    Mensagem = lib.t1.Mensagem,
                    DataLib = lib.t1.DataLib,
                    Vendedor = lib.t1.Vendedor,
                    Cliente = lib.t1.Cliente,
                    Filial = lib.t1.Filial
                }).ToList();

            return lista;
        }

        public List<ItensLib> PegaItensLib()
        {
            var lista = contexto.ItensLibs.Join(
                contexto.Liberacoes,
                t1 => t1.IdOrcamento,
                t2 => t2.IdOrcamento,
                (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
                .Where(a => a.t1.IdOrcamento == a.t2.IdOrcamento)
                .Select(itens => new ItensLib
                {
                    Produto = itens.t1.Produto,
                    Qtde = itens.t1.Qtde,
                    Unitario = itens.t1.Unitario,
                    Custo = itens.t1.Custo,
                    CustoDiario = itens.t1.CustoDiario,
                    UltCondicao = itens.t1.UltCondicao,
                    Total = itens.t1.Total
                }).ToList();

            return lista;
        }
    }
```

Aqui vai

```
[Table("LIBERACAO")]
    public class Liberacao
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("ID_LIBERACAO")]
        public int IdLiberacao { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_LIBERACAO")]
        public byte FlagLiberacao { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_ORCAMENTO")]
        public float IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_VENDEDOR")]
        public int IdVendedor { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDEDOR")]
        public string Vendedor { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_FILIAL")]
        public int IdFilial { get; set; }
        [Column("FILIAL")]
        public string Filial { get; set; }
        [Column("DATALIB")]
        public float DataLib { get; set; }
        [Column("HORALIB")]
        public float HoraLib { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_CLIENTE")]
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        [Column("CLIENTE")]
        public string Cliente { get; set; }
        [Column("TIPO_VENDA")]
        public string TipoVenda { get; set; }
        [Column("JUROS")]
        public float Juros { get; set; }
        [Column("DESCONTO")]
        public float Desconto { get; set; }
        [Column("VENCIMENTO")]
        public float Vencimento { get; set; }
        [Column("ACRESCIMO")]
        public float Acrescimo { get; set; }
        [Column("ENTRADA")]
        public float Entrada { get; set; }
        [Column("PRAZO")]
        public float Prazo { get; set; }
        [Column("TOTAL_LIQUIDO")]
        public float TotalLiquido { get; set; }
        [Column("MIN_TOTAL")]
        public float MinTotal { get; set; }
        [Column("USUARIO")]
        public string Usuario { get; set; }
        [Column("CUSTODIARIO")]
        public decimal CustoDiario { get; set; }
        [Column("MAX_COMI")]
        public decimal MaxComi { get; set; }
        [Column("VALOR_COMI")]
        public decimal ValorComi { get; set; }
        [Column("NOVA_COMI")]
        public decimal NovaComi { get; set; }
        [Column("MENSSAGEM")]
        public string Mensagem { get; set; }
        [Column("Menssagem_RET")]
        public string MensagemRet { get; set; }
        [Column("DataRetorno")]
        public decimal DataRetorno { get; set; }
        [Column("HoraRetorno")]
        public decimal HoraRetorno { get; set; }
        [Column("TempoProcesso")]
        public decimal TempoPrecesso { get; set; }
        [Column("Tipo")]
        public int Tipo { get; set; }
        [Column("PROGRAMA")]
        public string Programa { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PC")]
        public string NomePc { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PROCEDURE")]
        public string NomeProcedure { get; set; }
        [Column("Perc_Juros_Total")]
        public decimal PercJurosTotal { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_CULTURAVENCIDA")]
        public byte FlagCulturaVencida { get; set; }
        [Column("CULTURA")]
        public string Cultura { get; set; }
        [Column("CULTURA_VCTO")]
        public int CulturaVcto { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_PRORROGADO")]
        public byte FlagProrrogado { get; set; }
        [Column("VALOR_PRORROGADO")]
        public decimal ValorProrrogado { get; set; }
        [Column("DIAS_ATRASO")]
        public int DiasAtrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_VENDEDOR2")]
        public int IdVendedor2 { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDEDOR2")]
        public string Vendedor2 { get; set; }
        [Column("COMISSAO_VEND2")]
        public decimal ComissaoVend2 { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_COTACAO")]
        public byte FlagCotacao { get; set; }
        [Column("TipoVenda")]
        public string TipoVenda1 { get; set; }
        [Column("Flag_Receber_Atrasado")]
        public byte FlagReceberAtrazado { get; set; }
        [Column("Autorizou_Receber_Atrasado")]
        public string AutorizouReceberAtrazado { get; set; }
```

**EDIT2**:
Alterei para essa forma e funcionou

```
public IEnumerable<object> getAutoriza()
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes.Join(
                contexto.ItensLibs, lib => lib.IdOrcamento, itens => itens.IdOrcamento, (lib, itens) => new { lib, itens })
                .Where(a => a.lib.IdOrcamento == a.itens.IdOrcamento)
                .Select(libera => new
                {
                    libera.lib.TipoVenda,
                    libera.lib.Vencimento,
                    libera.lib.Juros,
                    libera.lib.Entrada,
                    libera.lib.Acrescimo,
                    libera.lib.Desconto,
                    libera.lib.Mensagem,
                    libera.lib.DataLib,
                    libera.lib.Vendedor,
                    libera.lib.Cliente,
                    libera.lib.Filial,
                    libera.itens.Produto,
                    libera.itens.Qtde,
                    libera.itens.Unitario,
                    libera.itens.Custo,
                    libera.itens.CustoDiario,
                    libera.itens.UltCondicao,
                    libera.itens.Total
                }).ToList();

            return lista;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere o `Select` para

```
.Select(lib => new Liberacao
{
    TipoVenda = lib.t1.TipoVenda,
    // e assim por diante
}
```

Obviamente isso só vai funcionar se você **realmente** for devolver uma lista de **`Liberacao`**.

Comment: O problema é que eu tenho duas entidades(Liberacao e ItensLib) e o new é apenas um(Liberacao). Como eu coloco no select a outra entidade?

Comment: Como eu disse, o objeto **tem que ser** do tipo `Liberacao`, senão não faz sentido tentar devolver uma lista deste tipo.

Comment: Não resolveu meu problema. Dá esse erro: `1>C:\Labs\AutorizadorService\AutorizadorService\Models\Autoriza.cs(25,21,25,30): error CS0200: Property or indexer 'Liberacao.TipoVenda' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
` Isso aco tece para todos os campos.

Comment: Bom, eu não tenho como adivinhar o que está acontecendo. Poste o model que eu tento ajudar.

Comment: Não, jovem. Eu preciso ver o modelo `Liberacao`